# Where does this bike comes from?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

[image][image]I have a bicycle (bike) bought in January 2000.
I am now curious to find out the manufacturer depending on the chassis serial number as engraved below the pedal-hub as indicated: ISR8080906.
Attached are some pics taken.

Comment: The head badge says "Jamis" as in https://www.jamisbikes.com/usa/index.html

Comment: I emailed and consulted with Jamis Support and they said no! The serial number does not comes from Jamis record. He also mentioned that the head-badge could be from some other jamis bike. Oh dear!

Comment: Pedantically answering the question as asked: Taiwan, probably.

Comment: If Jamis says its not theirs, then you've got useful info.  Someone's probably slapped any-old sticker on after stripping off all the frame's paint.   Just ride it and maintain it.

Comment: Drats! I bought that new! :-) On another site, Asian Serial Numbers Guide, someone also quoted a very similar serial number. In 2018 he posted the number as SR9206336. Mine is SR8080906. The poster suspect it could be either from Raleigh or Schwin?

Comment: @ThunderLooi you're confusing serial number with VIN as used on cars, which have to be globally unique.  Bike serial numbers may not even be unique inside that manufacturer.

Comment: @Criggie, understood about the VIN. Unique chassis numbers make it so much more difficult to correctly identify the bike. I email santacruz and was told it is not theirs, might be a "specialized frame/chassis.

Comment: Google image search can sometimes help - but there's an awful lot of MTB frames out there with minimal differences.  Can you go back through old paperwork, sales receipts, warranty docs, or even old bank statements to identify where it came from?  Then ask that shop?

Answer (score 0):

A previous neighbor got the same sticker on his bike and it came from Jamis. I gave him a hand installing the headache rack, [truxedo](https://4wheelonline.com/TruXedo-Tonneau-Covers.222468) tonneau and railings on his truck last year, his bike was lying on one corner of his garage. They don't have the same resemblance as far as I remember.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Same head-badge but perhaps different frame or chassis. Anyway, Jamis Bike replied it is not theirs.